# Usando sanitize do filter_var() com pdo, preciso usar os statements?

Tags: php, mysql, segurança

Gostaria de saber se mesmo já usando o filter_var com sanitize é preciso usar os statements do pdo.

É seguro fazer dessa forma? ou preciso usar por exemplo o bindValue()

```
<?php

$con=conectar();

//Recebe número da pagina, caso não exista recebe valor 1
$pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? filter_var($_GET['pg'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : 1;

//Variaveis
$polo = isset($_GET['polo']) ? filter_var($_GET['polo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;
$tipo = isset($_GET['tipo']) ? filter_var($_GET['tipo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;

//Config paginação
$limite = 2;
$inicio = ($pg*$limite) - $limite;

if(!empty($polo) && empty($tipo)) {

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = $polo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
    $contador = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cursos WHERE polo = $polo")->fetchColumn();

}else if(empty($polo) && !empty($tipo)) {

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE tipo = $tipo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
    $contador = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cursos WHERE tipo = $tipo")->fetchColumn();

}else if (empty($polo) && empty($tipo)) {

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
    $contador = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cursos")->fetchColumn();

}else {

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = $polo AND tipo = $tipo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
    $contador = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cursos WHERE polo = $polo AND tipo = $tipo")->fetchColumn();

}

$puxa_cursos = $con->prepare($consulta);
$puxa_cursos->execute();
```

Comment: Acho que a pergunta poderia ser inversa, qual o motivo para não usar?

Comment: Para evitar escrever linhas de código que talvez não precise, achei que tinha sido claro na pergunta.